# How can I connect a serial device to a Raspberry Pi without a USB to serial adapter?

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, usb, pyserial

I am trying to connect a serial device (specifically, an aerosol particle counter) to the Pi. Currently, I have a USB to serial adapter connecting the Pi and the device. When I run this program to read data from the serial device:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
print "connected"

ser.flushInput()

time.sleep(1)

while True:
    ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
    resp = ser.readline()
    print resp
    time.sleep(1)
```

I see two numbers printed to the console (aerosol particle counts):

```
56,4
63,2
68,1
42,2
72,9
62,8
74,5
77,7
73,4
54,6
65,6
67,2
65,1
80,4
```

These numbers fluctuate according to the particle count in the room. In other words, this code is working correctly.

However, I would like to get rid of this USB-serial adapter. So, I directly connected the TX, RX and ground pins with wires (TX on Pi to RX on device and vice versa). Now when I run a similar program with `/dev/ttyAMA0` in place of `/dev/ttyUSB0`:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0')
print "connected"

ser.flushInput()

time.sleep(1)

while True:
    resp = ser.read(1)
    print ord(resp)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I see this printed to the console:

```
100
230
77
166
207
15
0
101
102
154
51
121
61
0
101
153
154
153
158
61
0
```

This pattern of six numbers followed by a zero continues as the program is run.

Note: The reason I am running a 'similar' program and not the same program is because the readline() function, which reads bytes from the device until a new line character is read, does not work with the straight serial connection because there is no new line character in the serial data. Instead, with the straight serial data the Pi reads each byte and prints it's unicode character number. On the other hand, the data read in with the USB-serial converter connection does contain a new line character.

I am wondering how I can get the particle counts that were being shown with the USB-serial converter from the serial connection (RX/TX) instead.

Other info:

- Python 2.7.11
- 'serial' documentation: http://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#classes
- baud rate is 9600 for both connections
- no parity for both connections
- the read(bytes) function reads the corresponding number of bytes from the device
- the readline() function reads bytes from the device until a new line character
- ord('char') is a built in Python function that returns the corresponding integer for the Unicode character that is the argument
- inWaiting() gives the number of bytes that are in the Pi's input buffer
- Pi model: A
- OS: Raspbian wheezy

Thanks

Comment: why do you sleep always one second until you read the next char? I'd guess it should work without working. By pausing always for one second you may be to too slow.

Comment: @Pyfisch if I don't pause, all of the same numbers still get printed but a lot faster. Specifically, each group of seven numbers (the last one being zero) get printed out all at once, then the next seven, then the next seven, etc

Comment: Of course they are printed faster because you get all the data. Otherwise you accumulate an always growing delay in the data received.

Comment: Your hardware descriptions are vague.  Does this *"particle counter"* have an RS-232 interface?  What  *"TX, RX and ground pins"* are you using?  Are you using a RS-232 level-shifter (e.g. MAX3232) board?  *"Instead, with the straight serial data the Pi reads each byte and prints it's unicode character number."* -- That doesn't sound like a serial port.  Also that statement is not a fact, but a guess on what you think you have observed.

Comment: @sawdust The Met One 80080 Two Channel Particle Counter has an RS-232 interface. On the particle counter I am using pins 3 (RS-232 TX out), 5 (RS-232 ground), 6 (RS-232 RX in). On the RPi, I am using pins (board pin numbering) 6 (ground), 8 (UART0_TXD), 10 (UART0_RXD). I have ground connected to ground, TX to RX, and RX to TX. I am not using a level-shifter. And I will edit the question explaining that last part of your comment

Comment: You cannot directly connect RS-232 data pins to the RPi pins.  You need a RS-232 transceiver or level shifter to translate the different voltages and reverse logic.  That could account for the unexpected data that you receive.  You could damage the RPi due to the larger and negative voltages.  BTW RxD on pin 6 of a DB9 is unusual.  http://codeandlife.com/2012/07/01/raspberry-pi-serial-console-with-max3232cpe/

Comment: @sawdust Ok, I will try a level shifter, Thanks

Comment: Depending on how quickly you want it, you could get one from [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/RS232-converter-board-Female-3-3V/dp/B005D5T292/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) or [AliExpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/MAX3232-RS232-to-TTL-Serial-Port-Converter-Module-DB9-Connector-MAX232/32301551703.html).  I have both, and they perform about the same.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can be problematic is the fact that the PIs serial pins work with 3v3 logic not 5v. If your sensor is sending data in 5v logic it can mess with the PI.

Another thing you should check if you have enabled a linux terminal session on ttyAMA0. This is an option you can set in `/boot/cmdline.txt`

You may see an entry like `console=ttyAMA0,115200`. Remove that and reboot.